# Detecting touch ID scan duration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

I want to integrate touch ID to my iOS app.  I have integrated that but I want to do is while the sensor scans the fingerprint of the user I want to show a popup view and after successfully scan user should be redirected to another `UIViewController`. 
How can I detect the the time period that sensor scan the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before your call to [LAContext evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:] mark the time you started the authorization. in the completionHandler (aka reply) mark the time it is called

==> you have approximate duration (delta between the dates)

---

so show a viewController before calling, [LAContext evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:], hide it/redirect when done and reply is called

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the amount of time that the finger is pressed to the sensor, then this is not possible. The only thing you can get from the `LocalAuthentication` API is whether a biometrics policy exists, and whether or not the attempt at authentication passes or fails. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/).

Comment: How? I would really like to know.

Comment: I posted an answer. maybe I don't get the issue though - but AFAICS it is simple :D

Comment: I wont speak for the person who asked, but I think he is asking for the amount of time the finger is pressed to the scanner. What you answered is right, but we'll have to see if that's what OP wants.

Comment: revoked vote. if the op wants THAT exactly, he can't get it, right